# Where does the "arguments" variable come from in "this.callParent(arguments)"?

Tags: javascript, extjs4

While learning ExtJS 4, I found out that while defining a new class, in the `initComponent` method the constructor of the parent class can be called using `this.callParent(arguments)`.

I would like to know where this `arguments` variable (I know it can be `args` or `a` or `arg` too) is defined, and where its value is assigned.

For example, if I define my class as follows:

```
Ext.define('shekhar.MyWindow', {

  extend : 'Ext.Window',
  title : 'This is title',

  initComponent : function() {
    this.items = [
      // whatever controls to be displayed in window
    ];

    // I have not defined argument variable anywhere
    // but still ExtJS will render this window properly without any error
    this.callParent(arguments);
  }

});
```

Does anyone know where this `arguments` variable is defined, and how values are assigned to it?

Comment: Argument in this case is "shekhar.MyWindow"

Comment: I answered this on another similar post at http://stackoverflow.com/a/32855950/1019307

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `arguments` variable is a special variable in Javascript, available within any function. It's not a true array, but it contains the argument values passed to the function which can be accessed like array elements (so, `arguments[0]` is the first argument, `arguments[1]` is the second, and so on).

Check out [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) on the Mozilla Developer Network for more information and examples.